# How to create a new nested list from a function and an existing nested list in python?

Tags: python, list

What's the most pythonic way to do this? I don't mind using some third party libraries.
For example:

```
[['a','b'],[['c'],[['d']]],['e']] -> [['A','B'],[['C'],[['D']]],['E']]
```

I could do this in ugly way, but I want a pythonic way.

Comment: At this juncture, it is very unclear. Do you want to capitalize every entry in the list of lists?

Comment: this has nothing to do with nesting. this is casing?

Comment: @ha9u63ar: I'm not sure why you say it has nothing to do with nesting.  There are different depths to handle in the list.

Comment: The question is not clear enough. When we dealing with nesting, the depth of nesting matters a lot. Usually my principle is doing this case by case. Do not generalize something you don't need, because sometime it just not worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use recursion to apply the function to anything not a list:

```
def apply_recursive(ob, func):
    if not isinstance(ob, list):
        return func(ob)
    return [apply_recursive(elem, func) for elem in ob]
```

Demo:

```
>>> def apply_recursive(ob, func):
...     if not isinstance(ob, list):
...         return func(ob)
...     return [apply_recursive(elem, func) for elem in ob]
... 
>>> apply_recursive([['a','b'],[['c'],[['d']]],['e']], str.upper)
[['A', 'B'], [['C'], [['D']]], ['E']]
```

You can extend this to support any sequence that is not a string:

```
from collections import Sequence
try:
    string_type = basestring
except NameError:
    string_type = str

def apply_recursive(ob, func):
    if not isinstance(ob, Sequence) or isinstance(ob, string_type):
        return func(ob)
    return [apply_recursive(elem, func) for elem in ob]
```

which then supports tuples too:

```
>>> apply_recursive([('a','b'),[('c',),(['d'],)],['e']], str.upper)
[['A', 'B'], [['C'], [['D']]], ['E']]
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for **most pythonic** way is using a recursion function and list comprehension as following :

```
>>> def changer(li):
...   return [i.upper() if not isinstance(i,list) else changer(i) for i in li]
...
```

DEMO:

```
>>> l=[['a','b'],[['c'],[['d']]],['e']]  
>>> changer(l)
[['A', 'B'], [['C'], [['D']]], ['E']]
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to apply *any generic function* to the elements.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i don't think so! ;) as he doesn't tell any thing about this!